# google map with clusters is not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerclusterer

I have a google map on which i am using clusters like this

```
script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var script = '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cluster';
      if (document.location.search.indexOf('compiled') !== -1) {
        script += '_compiled';
      }
      script += '.js"><' + '/script>';
      document.write(script);
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      google.load('maps', '3', {
        other_params: 'sensor=false'
      });
      google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
      function initialize() {
        var GPS = <%=GPS %>
        var map_center = new google.maps.LatLng(31.2330555556,72.3330555556);
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          zoom: 6,
          center: map_center,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 
          if (markerClusterer) {
          markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
        }  
        var markers = [];       
        for(i=0; i<GPS.length; i++)
         { 
         var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(imageUrl,
          new google.maps.Size(24, 32));
         var imageUrl = 'ico/' + GPS[i].ICON;        
           markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: GPS[i].GPS,
           draggable: true,
           icon: markerImage,
           Info: '<table frame=box><tr><td align="Left"><font face="Arial" size=2 color=#336699>Shop Name:</td><td align="Left"><font face="Arial" size=2>'+ GPS[i].SHOP + '</font></td></tr><tr>'+
          '<td align="Left"><font face="Arial" size=2 color=#336699>Owner:</td><td align="Left"><font face="Arial" size=2>'+ GPS[i].OWNER + '</font></td></tr>'+
          '<td align="Left"><font face="Arial" size=2 color=#336699>Mobile:</td><td align="Left"><font face="Arial" size=2>'+ GPS[i].MOBILE + '</font></td></tr>'+
          '<tr><td align="Left"><font face="Arial" size=2 color=#336699>Distributer:</td><td align="Left"><font face="Arial" size=2>'+ GPS[i].DIST + '</font></td></tr><tr>'+
          '<tr><td align="Left"><font face="Arial" size=2 color=#336699>Region:</td><td align="Left"><font face="Arial" size=2>'+ GPS[i].REGION + '</font></td></tr>'+
          '<tr><td align="Left"></td><td align="Left"><font face="Arial" size=2 color=#336699><a target=_blank href=http://221.120.216.52/elp/sfpl/sfpl.php?ccode=01&amp;&regno='+ GPS[i].REGNO +'>View</a></td></tr>'+
          '</table>',
          title:GPS[i].SHOP + '(' +GPS[i].DIST + ')'
          });
          markers.push(markers);
          google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(this.Info);
            infowindow.open(map,this);
            });   
        }
       var markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
      }
    </script>
```

Here u can check http://dnet.sml.com.pk/map/SFPLSurvey.aspx
When Map Loads it is Like Freezed mean Dont moves with Mouse.When I Click on Pan to Move then It Starts maving.Plz any one Help I want that map should move when it loads by user

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert but var GPS = <%=GPS %> seems to be dumping a lot of information into the page. It very well maybe this that is causing the map to freeze. For the purpose of debugging drop the number of pulled data and see if the map performs as you intend it to.

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having all that data loaded as part of the page, use [AJAX](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic11.htm) techniques to load it after the map has rendered.

[Marker Clusterer example that loads data from XML](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3_clustered.html) (you can also use JSON).